# Сохранение переменной LD_LIBRARY_PATH в Linux

Tags: linux, centos, переменные-среды

Авторизуюсь за **root** и прописываю в ~/.bash_profile следующее:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Далее релог, и проверяю:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

И вижу то что и прописывал: `/usr/local/lib64`

Делаю то же самое для другого пользователя, но `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` выдаёт пустоту.

Что не так?

Подключаюсь к удаленному серверу на CentOS 7 по **ssh**

Comment: @Mike релог - это exit, закрытие терминала и открытие его снова, новое подключение по ssh. Пробовал прописывать и в $HOME/.bashrc и в $HOME/.bash_ profile - безрезультатно, переменная пустая при следующем входе в истему.

Comment: А у пользователя какой shell стоит ? Может не bash и тогда у него свои файлы старта сеанса. Для bash .bashrc или .bash_profile должны помогать. Можете в них для проверки какой нибудь echo написать, убедится что при входе пользователя строка эта будет выведена на экран (см. на пользователя в /etc/passwd). И вы же под $HOME точно домашний каталог нужного пользователя подразумевали (там же в passwd проверьте что это он)

Comment: @Mike ага, вот где собака зарыта. у рута bin/bash, а у этого пользователя оказалось /bin/sh. Огромное спасибо! Тогда вытекающий вопрос: где лежат аналогичные файлы для /bin/sh или как сменить пользователю оболочку и какие последствия это может повлечь?

Comment: /bin/sh скорее всего ссылка на какой нибудь другой shell (посмотрите в /bin не является ли он ссылкой). просто sh обычно не используется. но если это он, то $HOME/.profile (кстати он для многих оболочек может быть рабочим). Менять шелл можно с помощью chsh https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh или просто поправьте в /etc/passwd. Последствий обычно никаких. Если сложных не bash скриптов тот пользовтель не писал (что очень вряд ли, учитывая что вы ранее не знали какой у него шелл :) )

Comment: @Mike проверил, странно, но /bin/sh ведет на /bin/bash, при этом сменив у того самого пользователя в /etc/passwd оболочку на /bin/bash переменные из ~/.bash_profile и ~/.bashrc заработали. А так же ранее некоторые команды, вызываемые тем пользователем из /bin/sh выдавали bash: permission denied. Главный вопрос, в общем-то, закрыт, но.. как так?)

Comment: Хм. не знал такой особенности bash. Многие программы в unix ведут себя так, как называются. Для многих операций делается одна программа и кладутся ссылки на нее. Видимо bash пользуется той же техникой и меняет свое поведение в зависимости от того как вызван. например начинает эмулировать поведение стандартного sh (это только предположение, но думаю правильное)